# Why does shinyapps fail to deploy when it requires edgeR or limma Bioconductor packages?

Tags: r, shiny, bioconductor

I am having trouble deploying an app which requires `edgeR` and `limma` packages, via shinyapps.io. The app is running locally without any problem and I can deploy any other app which doesn't require `limma` and `edgeR`. However, I am receiving the following error during deployment of the app using edgeR:

```
An error has occurred
The application failed to start.

Attaching package: ‘DT’
The following objects are masked from ‘package:shiny’:

dataTableOutput, renderDataTable

Loading required package: edgeR
Warning in library(package, lib.loc = lib.loc, 
character.only = TRUE, logical.return = TRUE,  :
there is no package called ‘edgeR’

Error in value[[3L]](cond) : unable to find required package ‘edgeR’
Calls: local ... tryCatch -> tryCatchList -> tryCatchOne -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted"

> devtools::session_info()
Session info -----------------------------
setting  value                       
version  R version 3.3.0 (2016-05-03)
system   x86_64, mingw32             
ui       RStudio (0.99.879)          
language (EN)                        
collate  English_Australia.1252      
tz       Australia/Sydney            
date     2016-05-15                  

Packages -----------------------------

package       * version  date       source                            
BiocInstaller   1.22.2   2016-05-12 Bioconductor                      
bitops          1.0-6    2013-08-17 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
curl            0.9.7    2016-04-10 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
devtools        1.11.1   2016-04-21 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
digest          0.6.9    2016-01-08 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
git2r           0.14.0   2016-03-13 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
htmltools       0.3.5    2016-03-21 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
httpuv          1.3.3    2015-08-04 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
httr            1.1.0    2016-01-28 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
memoise         1.0.0    2016-01-29 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
mime            0.4      2015-09-03 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
packrat         0.4.7-1  2016-03-28 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
R6              2.1.2    2016-01-26 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
Rcpp            0.12.4   2016-03-26 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
RCurl           1.95-4.8 2016-03-01 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
RJSONIO         1.3-0    2014-07-28 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
rsconnect       0.4.1.11 2016-05-15 Github (rstudio/rsconnect@2419667)
rstudioapi      0.5      2016-01-24 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
shiny         * 0.13.2   2016-03-28 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
shinyapps     * 0.4.1.8  2016-05-15 Github (rstudio/shinyapps@4dd3a9d)
withr           1.0.1    2016-02-04 CRAN (R 3.3.0)                    
xtable          1.8-2    2016-02-05 CRAN (R 3.3.0)
```

`appDependencies()` also does not display `edgeR` package as you can see from below:

```
> appDependencies()
package version source
1           DT     0.1   CRAN
2           R6   2.1.2   CRAN
3         Rcpp  0.12.4   CRAN
4       digest   0.6.9   CRAN
5    htmltools   0.3.5   CRAN
6  htmlwidgets     0.6   CRAN
7       httpuv   1.3.3   CRAN
8     jsonlite  0.9.20   CRAN
9     magrittr     1.5   CRAN
10        mime     0.4   CRAN
11     packrat 0.4.7-1   CRAN
12       shiny  0.13.2   CRAN
13      xtable   1.8-2   CRAN
14        yaml  2.1.13   CRAN
```

But as far as I've read from other forums, this is not necessarily the cause of the problem.

I reckon I am having the same issue as in this [post](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/shinyapps-users/JnJNK5Ej9-Y).

I'd appreciate if someone can help with this issue.

P.S. `limma` package also generates the same problem.

Comment: Did you installed it from the github page as they recommend in the group?